# Save GCM Registration And Login User

Tags: android, architecture, android-asynctask, authorization, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android app where users receive push notifications about some reminders and events  they set on the website.

App. enables users to see their reminders (set on the website) but first of course asks them to log in.

App exchanges data through `HTTP` web service with server.

Since I have push notifications functionality I need to register app and get `registration_id`  and save it along with `user_id` in my server.

My question is - **When should I get the registration id?** I want `LoginActivity` to be the First screen for users.

I have tried to get `registration_id` when user `log in` is successful and send it back to my server together with `user_id` hoping that `finish()`-ing the `LoginActivity` can not  cancel `AsyncTask` (which sends `registration_id` to server).

How do you think is better? - Consider there might be cases when user might be logged in but getting new `registration_id` was still necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the registration to GCM should be unrelated to when the login takes place, since if a user logs off and another user logs in, the registration ID doesn't change, so you don't have to perform a new GCM registration.

You should call `GoogleCloudMessaging.register` when your app is first launched (or when it's first launched after a new version is installed), and persist the registration ID you get in SharedPreferences.

Then, when a user logs in successfully, you can send to your server both the user ID and the registration ID, and associate the two in your DB.

When the user logs out, send a request to your server that would remove the association of the user and the registration ID.

If you get a new registration ID when user is already logged in (for example after a new version is installed), you can send the registration ID with the ID of the logged in user when you get the new registration ID from GCM.